# Python pool process management

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I was running some Python code and realized when I instantiate `Pool` with only one process, for instance:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from time import sleep

def f(i):
  print(i)
  sleep(10)

with Pool(1) as p:
    p.map(f, [i for i in range(100)])
```

Actually five processes are currently running. I've also noticed a pattern going on: if I instantiate `Pool` with 1, 2,3,... processes the number of processes launched by Python are 5,6,7,... I'm curious: Does `Pool` use three process for management?

Comment: Are you sure you are seeing processes and not threads?

Comment: @Javier, I think so. When I look at top (linux) they have different pids.

Comment: They do get different PIDs. Use htop and hide threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `Pool(1)`, you will get 2 processes, the main process (pid 31070), and one worker process (pid 31071), but 3 extra [threads/LWPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-weight_process) in the main process (LWP/thread id 31072/31073/31074):

```
  PID  PPID   LWP  NLWP CMD
31070 21240 31070     4 python3 so_48968836_mp.py
31070 21240 31072     4 python3 so_48968836_mp.py
31070 21240 31073     4 python3 so_48968836_mp.py
31070 21240 31074     4 python3 so_48968836_mp.py
31071 31070 31071     1 python3 so_48968836_mp.py
```

[those three threads](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L176-L200) are for pool workers maintaining, async task and result handling.